# Как заставить скрипт работать при использовании метода load

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

Здравствуйте.

Как заставить скрипт работать при использовании метода load.

У меня возвращается просто код скрипта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать нужно прослойку [WSGI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSGI) между Apache и Python, что бы веб сервер мог интепритировать питон скрипт. В Apache нужно установить Mod_wsgi.

Answer (score 1):

Загрузить AJAX'ом Python-скрипт и выполнить его не получится. В браузерах нет интерпретатора Python'а, а запустить из браузера интерпретатор, установленный на компьютере клинета, не позволит политика безопасности браузера.

**UPD**

Поспешил с ответом. Оказывается, есть [JS-интерпретатор Python'а](http://www.skulpt.org/).